# Elastic Beanstalk Docker container to access S3 bucket for data

Tags: docker, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have very simple flask project with just one end point that I was able to deploy into AWS using Elastic Beanstalk

The only exposed end point goes to S3 retrieves a csv file and publish data in raw format, this configuration is working fine, so I know the roles and permissions at elastic beanstalk work correctly to reach the S3 bucket.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import io
import boto3
import pandas as pd

application = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(application)

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = 'my_bucket'
key = 'my_file.csv'

class Home(Resource):
  def get(self):
    
    try:
      s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
      obj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()['Body']
      data = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj.read()))
      print("S3 Object loaded.")
    except:
      print("S3 Object could not be opened.")
      
    print(data)
    csv = data.to_csv(index=False)
    return csv

#End points definition and application raise up
api.add_resource(Home, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Now I'm trying to move that to a container so I created a Dockerfile to encapsulate the minimal app:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

Since I don't have additional volumes or anything extra  my Dockerrun.aws.json is barely empty

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1"
}
```

I'm missing something to procure the access to the S3 bucket from inside the container?

Comment: Not sure, what is the issue? Any error messages?

Comment: I thought that I might be missing some way to pass permissions from the EC2 instance to the container but I just realized that I was not exposing the port at the docker file and that's why it was not able to deploy correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While debugging I figured out that I was not exposing the port at the dockerfile and therefore it was not able to deploy the container correctly. I also added python as an entry point and the script name as the cmd.

Finally after some investigation also realized that the container inherits all role permissions that the host has so there is not need to do any additional task

My docker file end up looking like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```